# Filter Search Results Based On Link Clicked

Tags: search, 2013, search-results, filter, search-scope

I am using SharePoint 2013 and have links on the home page such as (Tax, Assurance, Advisory). Does anyone know how I can in SP 2013 use one search page but filter out the results depening on the link that was clicked (Tax, Assurance, Adivsory).  I tried QueryParameter in query builder but that seems to be broken (Doesnt work with refinements)? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I know how to construct a URL paired to a filter in 2010, but won't re-hash that if you're saying you know it to not work in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your site structure or the structure of the data, the only reliable way would be to create custom Search Scopes and configure them to include only the desired content for those specific categories.  You would then add the proper scope to the querystring when building the link.

A possible alternative is available if the desired filter can be configured as a Refiner then it is just a matter of adding that to the querystring using the refiner syntax.  However, this option depends heavily on the nature and structure of the data as not all field types can be used in refiner filters.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave, SP2013 doesnt have Search Scopes like 2010. I looked at "Results Sources" which replaces Search Scopes and it does have a QueryString parameter to filter by but its doesnt work with refiners. The problem is the Query String parameter uses the old style syntex ?Parm1=Val1&Parm2=Val2, etc... But when used with refiners SP puts a JSON structure in the URL so its breaks :(

Comment: The mechanics have changed a little but the functionality is still there.  Perhaps this might help : http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/02/01/how-query-rules-and-result-sources-can-be-used-to-customize-search-results.aspx

Comment: Dave I followed you suggestion by using result blocks. The problem is SP limits the amount of items in a result block to a maximum of 10. Which wont help since the results will contain more then 10 items. Maybe creating a custom web part is my only option.

Comment: If you edit the Search Results page, the number of items per page is a setting on the web part itself.  It can be set to anything but I think it has an internal limit of 50 items per page

Comment: Yes your correct, but a result block cant return more then 10 results overall regardless of the web part setting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tom it's hard to find documentation for this but at the end I resolved using this pattern:

```
resultspage.aspx#Default={"k":"*","r":[{"n":"owstaxIdYourManagedProp","t":["cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736"],"o":"OR","k":false,"m":{"cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736":"TermName"}}]}
```

It's important to note that: 
k:* basically it means "all documents" 
owstaxIdXXX is a typical name of managed property mapped to a termset 
cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736 is an example of termID inside your termstore 
TermName is an example of term name inside your termstore

If in your case Tax, Assurance, Advisory are just keywords it's much easier because you can just use (SP2013 format):

```
resultspage.aspx#Default={"k":"YOURKEYWORD"}
```